# Rust extend struct fields?

Tags: struct, rust

How to extend fields from a common struct to avoid code repetition. Suppose the common struct has a lot of fields and the extending struct has only some extra fields.
Eg .

```
struct CommonStruct {
  field_1:i32,
  field_2:i32,
  ...
  field_10:i32
}

struct ExtendedStruct1 {
  field_11:i32
}

struct ExtendedStruct2 {
  field_12:i32
}
```